# Assign a task to two or more persons in Jira

Tags: jira, code-inspection

I'm currently using Jira in a software development project and one of the activities on the project is a code review process. A developer creates a new code and then two or more other developer (usually senior developers) inspect that code.

I don't want to create two or more tasks for each code reviewer - instead I want to create a single task, name it like "New function - code review" and assign all code reviewer to this task. After having completed the code review each reviewer logs spent time into this single task.

Is it possible in Jira? If it isn't, then could you please advise me another approach?

Comment: A common solution is to have a "In Review" column on your board, and then assign it over to the reviewer as part of that process. Although you really should do this in your code-review tool, not as part of your tickets. Process heavy development like this doesn't benefit anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is that a single issue can't have more than one assignee. [This page on the Atlassian help site details a few workarounds](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/how-do-i-assign-issues-to-multiple-users-207489749.html).

I think the best workaround for your case would be to [create subtasks for each individual senior developer](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/creating-issues-and-sub-tasks-764478439.html) on each Code Review task.

Comment: The Code Review task is logically a sub-task of the main task (a sub-task of a task). So it is already a sub-task. We can't create a sub-task for a sub-task, right?

Comment: Yeah - that's correct. Looks like this solution won't work for your case, then.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other suggestions here, you could also create a custom user field that accepts multiple users, i.e. a "user picker" (or "multi user picker" in earlier Jira versions) field. However, this won't replace the typical "Assignee" field but could help you with your use case.

See also this question and answer on [community.atlassian.com](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-I-create-a-multi-user-custom-field/qaq-p/74372).